# How to upload to a AES256 encrypted AWS S3 bucket using active storage rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, encryption, rails-activestorage

I am trying to upload files to an AES encrypted S3 bucket using active storage. But it throws an access denied error(Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)).

Comment: Could you post the code that causes this error?

Comment: Hello, I think you might be uploading your files to S3 without specifying the encryption parameters

Comment: @FransDel We are not sure how to include the encryption parameters. Can you please help. In which file should we include the encryption parameters?

Comment: How are you uploading you files to s3? Via an SDK, CLI? In this case give us the code you are using. If you are uploading files via the console in the 3 option pane under the storage class options you have encryption options